# Why does Longest not work on OptionsPattern?

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, options, argument-patterns, optional-arguments

When having a function with optional arguments and options, I frequently find myself writing something like this:

```
f[Shortest[a_ : "default"], opts : OptionsPattern[]] := {a, {opts}}

f["a" -> 1]
(* {"default", {"a" -> 1}} *)

f[2]
(* {2, {}} *)

f[2, "a" -> 1]
(* {2, {"a" -> 1}} *)
```

What I would find more natural however is to use [`Longest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Longest.html) on the `OptionsPattern[]` part:

```
g[a_ : "default", opts : Longest@OptionsPattern[]] := {a, {opts}}

g["a" -> 1]
(* {"a" -> 1, {}} *)

g[2]
(* {2, {}} *)

g[2, "a" -> 1]
(* {2, {"a" -> 1}} *)
```

This would also be simpler to maintain if there are multiple optional arguments etc. But clearly, this does not work.

### Question

Why does `Longest` not have the expected effect here? The documentation mentions possible issues when "there are additional constraints in the pattern", but I don't really see any of those?

### Additional remarks

It seems that cooking up my own "`OptionsPattern`" also works:

```
h[a_ : "default", opts : Longest[(_Rule | _RuleDelayed) ..]] := {a, {opts}}

h["a" -> 1]
(* {"default", {"a" -> 1}} *)

h[2]
(* h[2] *)

h[2, "a" -> 1]
(* {2, {"a" -> 1}} *)
```

So it seems to be specific to `OptionsPattern`?